# Python Pandas - How to merge two dataframes that have two different columns to two list columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes.

df1 :

```
key  column_a 
AA   AAB      
AA   AAC      
AB   ABA      
AB   ABK
```

df2:

```
key  column_b
AA   AAA
AB   ABA
AB   ABK
AC   ACC
```

I wanted to merge them but the column_a and column_b would become a list.

```
key  column_a       column_b
AA   ['AAB','AAC']  ['AAA']
AB   ['ABA','ABK']  ['ABA','ABK']
AC   NaN            ['ACC']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If converting to lists, you lose the vectorised functionality which goes with using NumPy arrays held in contiguous memory blocks.

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate lambda function - remove `NaN`s and create `list`s:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('key').agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist())
print (df)
       column_a    column_b
key                        
AA   [AAB, AAC]       [AAA]
AB   [ABA, ABK]  [ABA, ABK]
AC           []       [ACC]
```

Last if need replace empty lists to `NaN`s use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df = df.where(df.astype(bool))
print (df)
       column_a    column_b
key                        
AA   [AAB, AAC]       [AAA]
AB   [ABA, ABK]  [ABA, ABK]
AC          NaN       [ACC]
```

Comment: Works great! I was wondering if it would be better to store column_a and column_b as a single column and just indicate which dataframe the column came from in another column. I'll go ask it in another question.

Comment: @MasakiAndou - Do you think something like `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=('a', 'b'))` ? Then get `NaN`s values.